# Generate a HTML tag from a JSON with Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a JSON file describing an x number of HTML elements and their content:

```
{
  "elements": [
    {
      "type" : "p",
      "content" : "Lorem Ipsum"
    },
    {
      "type" : "blockquote",
      "content" : "Lorem Ipsum",
      "by" : "Walter White"
    }
  ]
}
```

I have problem figuring out how to generate the described HTML elements on the view.

Am I approaching this in a completely wrong way? Those elements will compose a blog article.

I don't like to use markdown or directly save the HTML because I need every element to be editable from the front-end.

Comment: are you looking to only render the JSON content or incorporate two-way data binding so that you save any changes made in the frontend back to the JSON?

Comment: I don't need two-way binding, I can save all changes once the used finished the edit - the JSON is just a simplification, it will actually be a MongoDB object

Answer (score 2):

[**Here is a Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/happysmiles/gkt65523/6/)

I created a directive that can render HTML elements based on the data you've given. It's not yet refined but I think this will work.

```
angular.forEach(scope.elements, function(value, key) {
    // create an element based on its type
    var newElement = document.createElement(value.type);
    // add the content
    newElement.innerHTML = value.content;

    for (attribute in value) {
        if (attribute != 'type' && attribute != 'content') {
            //apply attribute
            newElement.setAttribute(attribute, value[attribute]);
        }
    }
    element.append(newElement);
});
```

**Limitations**

- Nested elements are not handled by this code (further refinements can handle that)
- This could be vulnerable to injection attacks, so I suggest you use the [ngSanitize](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize/service/$sanitize) module or something similar
- I'm not sure about the performance :)

This is to give you an idea that AngularJS can handle your concern.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I came up with this solution, It's not elegant, but it works.

```
<div ng-repeat="element in elements">
  <div ng-if="element.type == 'p'">
    <p>{{element.content}}</p>
  </div>
  <div ng-if="element.type == 'blockquote'">
    <blockquote>
      {{element.content}}
      <span>by {{element.by}}</span>
     </blockquote>
  </div>
</div>
```

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rdgda4pp/1/

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would proceed :

First of all you need to fetch the data inside a controller an expose them to the view using the $scope :

```
angular.module('app').controller('BlogCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){

$http({method: 'GET',url: '/blog/1/data'}).
        success(function (data) {
            if (data) {
                $scope.content = data;
            }
        })
      .error(function (error) {
          console.warn("Unable to retrieve data for this article");
      });

});
```

Inside your view, you would use your custom directive (we will come to it in a second) :

```
<div data-ng-controller="BlogCtrl">
  <dynamic-tag content="tag" ng-repeat="tag in content"></dynamic-tag >
</div>
```

Now, we have to tackle the most 'difficult' part : the directive. Our custom directive will generate the DOM elements according to your JSON definition.

```
angular.module('app').directive("dynamicTag",
            ['$document', '$compile', function($document, $compile) {

                var getTemplate = function(tag){
                    var template = '';
                    if (tag.type === 'p')
                     template += angular.element('<p>'+ tag.content + '</p>');
                    //Repeat and create elements for every tag you need to handle..

                    return template;
                }; 

                return {
                    restrict : 'E', 
                    replace: true,
                    scope: {
                        content:'=content'
                    },
                    link : function(scope, element, attrs) {                    
                        element.html(getTemplate(scope.content);
                        $compile(element.contents())(scope);
                    }
                };
            }]);
```

I have not tested my code, just wrote it from scratch. If you can't get it working, I can eventually make a plunker.